# How to highlight erros in visual studo code editor for c++ language?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I installed `C/C++ IntelliSense` version of `0.23.1` in visual studio code version of `1.35.1` in Ubuntu 18.04, and could not able to see error highlighting in the editor for c++.

[image: See C/C++ IntelliSense still not showing error]
I have manually changed some parameters in the `settings.json` file, but could not highlight when error present in the code.

This is the `settings.json` file of my visual studio code editor.

```
settings.json

{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Enabled",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0
}
```

What are the changes I need to do in `settings.json` or anything I'm missing?

Comment: This should work directly out-of-the-box. I.e. install vscode and then install c/c++ extension. Then open your project folder.  I have been using vscode version `1.33.1` and c/c++ extension version `0.22.2-insiders`. Can you just check what version you are using? - also is this on a linux box or windows? (not that it should matter - but I have not used it on windows).

Comment: I'm using `vscode` version of `1.35.1`, C/C++ extension version of `0.23.1`. and using Linux[ubuntu 18.04].

Comment: vscode `settings.json`
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Enabled",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0
}

Comment: I don't have any of these settings overided (other then zoom level). I suggest to try to remove all these settings (back them up first) and close/reopen vscode. Other then that maybe try the version that I have (I am not in a position to upgrade just yet but I will be trying that soon) - this is just in case there are any bugs in the newer version...?

Comment: I uninstalled everything vscode

and

I installed vscode version of `1.33.1` and C/C++ extension version of `0.22.1`. 

I can able to compile the c++ code and run the code as well, but

still I am not seeing error highlighting in the vscode.

Comment: oh wait - do you have cpp tools installed? `https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases` I have version 0.22.2. This is the OS specific dependency for c/c++ extension. I get the impression you have not installed this?

Comment: Probably the `cpptools-linux.vsix` is what you need... scroll down that page until you see it: `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.22.2-insiders`

Comment: I have installed the `cpptools` by downloading it from `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/download/0.22.2-insiders/cpptools-linux.vsix`, and installed with this command `code --install-extension cpptools-linux.vsix`. But still I am not seeing error highlighting in the vscode.

Comment: What version of linux do you have? - I can only say at the moment with Ubuntu 18.04 and vscode version I mentioned (and older versions) that this appeared to work out of the box and with no further config. Are you getting any error messages in the bottom right cornder when you load vscode? (if things went wrong it usually says there)

Comment: This is the only message, I can see here.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNnI9lR40pwoKW85tbRmbmZBHQIIPuOrBphL5_gMyWlknr90_YpfAKr9sTw7w_Qaw?key=dFpCRFlBY2JXNEZpX25ZSEIxU0ZESlJVbmpEckNR

Comment: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNnI9lR40pwoKW85tbRmbmZBHQIIPuOrBphL5_gMyWlknr90_YpfAKr9sTw7w_Qaw?key=dFpCRFlBY2JXNEZpX25ZSEIxU0ZESlJVbmpEckNR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195485/discussion-between-code-fodder-and-kasthuri-shravankumar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solutions is exactly what are you looking for, but I use 2 extensions for highlight errors and warnings when I realized intellisense doesn't provide a "easy to view" way for errors:

**Error Lens** (usernamehw.errorlens) for highlight the entire line and show on real time the error diagnostic

**Error Gutters** (igorsbitnev.error-gutters) for put error icons next of line number

Both look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Patricio, for answering.

Comment: Thanks, @Patricio, for answering. I installed `Error Lens` and `Error Gutters`, but still VS Code is not showing any error messages. If I declare a variable `int nam="Eggg"` It is just showing `Eggg` is an unknown word. That's all it is doing. It is not highlighting for syntax error for c++.